# Fuse- Implementing Write operation

Tags: filesystems, fuse

I am writing a custom fuse Mirror File System (in Ubuntu using FUSE-JNA). By mirror I mean, It will read from and write into a directory of local file system.

I implemented getattr, create, and read operation as below. All these work perfectly.

```
...
private final String mirroredFolder = "./target/mirrored";
...
...

    public int getattr(final String path, final StatWrapper stat)
{   

    File f = new File(mirroredFolder+path);         

    //if current path is of file
    if (f.isFile())
    {
        stat.setMode(NodeType.FILE,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true);
        stat.size(f.length());
        stat.atime(f.lastModified()/ 1000L);
        stat.mtime(0);
        stat.nlink(1);
        stat.uid(0);
        stat.gid(0);
        stat.blocks((int) ((f.length() + 511L) / 512L));
        return 0;
    }


    //if current file is of Directory
    else if(f.isDirectory())
    {
        stat.setMode(NodeType.DIRECTORY);
        return 0;
    }





    return -ErrorCodes.ENOENT();
}
```

below create method creates new file in mirrored folder

```
    public int create(final String path, final ModeWrapper mode, final FileInfoWrapper info)
{
    File f = new File(mirroredFolder+path);
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        mode.setMode(NodeType.FILE, true, true, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

read method reads file from mirrored folder

```
    public int read(final String path, final ByteBuffer buffer, final long size, final long offset, final FileInfoWrapper info)
{

    String contentOfFile=null;
    try {
        contentOfFile= readFile(mirroredFolder+path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final String s = contentOfFile.substring((int) offset,
            (int) Math.max(offset, Math.min(contentOfFile.length() - offset, offset + size)));
    buffer.put(s.getBytes());
    return s.getBytes().length;

}
```

But my write operation is not working.

Below is my Write method, which is incomplete.

```
public int write(final String path, final ByteBuffer buf, final long bufSize, final long writeOffset,
        final FileInfoWrapper wrapper)
{

    return (int) bufSize;
}
```

When I run it in Debugger mode, the path arguments shows Path=/.goutputstream-xxx  (where xxx is random alphanumeric each time write method is called)

Please guide me how to correctly implement write operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write to the filename you're given. [How do I create a file and write to it in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2885173/109696)

The reason you're seeing `path=/.goutputstream-xxx` is because of https://askubuntu.com/a/151124. This isn't a bug in fuse-jna.

Comment: if I get `/.goutputstream-xxx` in path argument then how would I know which file to write. for instance, if I edit and save file _abc.txt_. The path argument in write() method show `/.goutputstream-xxx` instead of currently edited file. I know its ubuntu  bug. I updated it to ubuntu version 14 from 12, but still the same problem. Which OS should now I try/ or any other solution.

Comment: You're getting `/.goutputstream-xxx` because of the lightdm bug which tries to write to those files, independently of the text editor writing `/abc.txt`. If you get `/.goutputstream-xxx`, then write to `/.goutputstream-xxx`. When the text editor saves, you will get `/abc.txt`. The function is called multiple times (once per block to write for each file).

Comment: Thanks. I completed this project and made it public here 

[Java FUSE Mirror File System](https://github.com/Syed-Rahman-Mashwani/Java-FUSE-Mirror-File-System)